# UIBarButtonSystemItemCamera is not centered on UIToolBar

Tags: iphone, ios, ios5, uitoolbar

I've got very simple code here

```
[mImagePickerToolBar setBarStyle:UIBarStyleBlackTranslucent];
[mImagePickerToolBar sizeToFit];
UIBarButtonItem *spaceItem1 = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemFlexibleSpace target:nil action:nil];
UIBarButtonItem *spaceItem2 = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemFlexibleSpace target:nil action:nil];

UIBarButtonItem *cameraItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemCamera target:self action:@selector(captureBarItemPressed:)];

NSArray *items = [NSArray arrayWithObjects: spaceItem1, cameraItem, spaceItem2, nil];

[mImagePickerToolBar setItems:items animated:NO];
```

on my UIToolBar camera item is not centered at all, see on the picture, in comparison with home button its a little bit right, why is this so and how to center it ?

[image]

Comment: Your button is in center but in UIBarButtonItem the image comes in center of button and but the button style is plain that why it is looking like that.You need to make your button style to bordered in order to show your button image in center.

Comment: Changing the style to bordered makes the camera button view to change, i.e. with borders around it ... is there a way for me to have plain view i.e. without borders around it and the item's view centered on UIToolBar ?

Comment: If I change to display custom image of camera, as the same as system camera icon ... will it be considered as a violation of Apples Human Interface Guidelines ?

Comment: How do you create and add the toolbar in the first place, and why are you calling sizeToFit on it?

Comment: I create toolbar like this mImagePickerToolBar = [[UIToolbar alloc] initWithFrame:toolBarFrmae]; and add it to current view with addSubView

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
[self.navigationController setToolbarHidden:NO];
toolbar = [[UIToolbar alloc] init];
toolbar.barStyle = UIBarStyleBlackOpaque;
[toolbar sizeToFit];
toolbar.frame = CGRectMake(0, 436, 320, 44);
UIBarButtonItem *spaceItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemFixedSpace target:nil action:nil];
spaceItem.width = 130.0;
UIBarButtonItem *cameraItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemCamera target:self action:@selector(captureBarItemPressed:)];
NSArray *items = [NSArray arrayWithObjects: spaceItem, cameraItem, nil];
[toolbar setItems:items];
[self.navigationController.view addSubview:toolbar];
```

This is working for me. Please make sure at your side

Comment: The point of the flexible space is so that you dont have to hard code spacing dimensions - I'm sure the questioners problem is elsewhere.

Comment: My Friends you are using UIBarButtonSystemItemFlexibleSpace right? just use UIBarButtonSystemItemFixedSpace instead of above and set its width property, it so easy.

Comment: I have added the code what i am using and dear it working. please check

Answer (score 2):

The flexible spaces *should* work. This is a bug in iOS, in my opinion. You can see for yourself by mocking this up in interface builder.

Here is the bordered button:

[image]

And here is the plain button:

[image]

It isn't even lined up within its own selection area.

Comment: yup, I also think its a bag ... temporarily I've done this with fixed spaces ... +1